# Pass command line args to node app while running

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, mean-stack

I was wondering whether there is a way to pass command line arguments to a node application after it has started running.

What I would like would be that I can type a number into the command line and then be able to access it from my javascript. I know about environment.args, but this would be passing the argument when you start the program, my issue is I might not know which number to pass until after the program has started and therefore it must be done through THE COMMAND LINE and AFTER EXECUTION HAS STARTED.

Thanks,